# Prolog: Debugging Recursive Source Removal Algorithm

Tags: debugging, prolog

I am currently working on implementing a source-removal topological sorting algorithm for a directed graph. Basically the algorithm goes like this:

1. Find a node in a graph with no incoming edges
2. Remove that node and all edges coming out from it and write its value down
3. Repeat 1 and 2 until you eliminate all nodes

So, for example, the graph

[image: Sample graph]

would have a topological sort of **a,e,b,f,c,g,d,h**. (Note: topological sorts aren't unique and thus there can be a different topological sort as well)

I am currently working on a Prolog implementation of this with the graph being represented in list form as follows:

> [ [a,[b,e,f]], [b,[f,g]], [c,[g,d]], [d,[h]], [e,[f]], [f,[]],
>   [g,[h]], [h,[]] ]

Where the **[a, [b,e,f] ]** term for example represents the edges going from **a** to **b**, **e**, and **f** respectively, and the **[b, [f,g] ]** term represents the edges going from **b** to **f** and **g**. In other words, the first item in the array "tuple" is the "from" node and the following array contains the destinations of edges coming from the "from" node.
I am also operating under assumption that there is one unique name for each vertex and thus when I find it, I can delete it without worrying about any potential duplicates.

I wrote the following code

```
    % depends_on shows that D is adjacent to A, i.e. I travel from A to D on the graph
% returns true if A ----> D
depends_on(G,A,D) :- member([A,Ns],G), member(D,Ns).

% doesnt_depend_on shows that node D doesnt have paths leading to it 
doesnt_depend_on(G, D) :- \+ depends_on(G, _, D).

% removes node from a graph with the given value
remove_graph_node([ [D,_] | T], D, T). % base case -- FOUND IT return the tail only since we already popped it
remove_graph_node([ [H,Ns] | T], D, R) :- \+ H=D,remove_graph_node( T, D, TailReturn), append([[H,Ns]], TailReturn, R).

%----------------------------------------------------
source_removal([], []]). % Second parameter is empty list due to risk of a cycle
source_removal(G,Toposort):-member([D,_], G), 
                            doesnt_depend_on(G,D), 
                            remove_graph_node(G,D,SubG),
                            source_removal(SubG, SubTopoSort),
                            append([D], SubTopoSort, AppendResult),
                            Toposort is AppendResult.
```

And I tested the `depends_on`, `doesnt_depend_on`, and `remove_graph_node` by hand using the graph `[ [a,[b,e,f]], [b,[f,g]], [c,[g,d]], [d,[h]], [e,[f]], [f,[]], [g,[h]], [h,[]] ]` and manually changing the parameter variables (especially when it comes to node names like **a**, **b**, **c** and etc). I can vouch after extensive testing that they work.

However, my issue is debugging the `source_removal` command. In it, I repeatedly remove a node with no directed edge pointing towards it along with its outgoing edges and then try to add the node's name to the `Toposort` list I am building.

At the end of the function's running, I expect to get an array of output like `[a,e,b,f,c,g,d,h]` for its `Toposort` parameter. Instead, I got

```
?- source_removal([ [a,[b,e,f]], [b,[f,g]], [c,[g,d]], [d,[h]], [e,[f]], [f,[]], [g,[h]], [h,[]] ], Result).
false.
```

I got **false** as an output instead of the list I am trying to build.

I have spent hours trying to debug the `source_removal` function but failed to come up with anything. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone would be willing to take a look at this with a different pair of eyes and help me figure out what the issue in the `source_removal` function is. I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks for the time spent reading this post and in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first clause for `source_removal/2` contained a typo (one superfluous closing square bracket).

The last line for the second clause in your code says `Toposort is AppendResult`. Note that `is` is used in Prolog to denote the evaluation of an arithmetic expression, e.g., `X is 3+4` yields `X = 7` (instead of just unifying variable `X` with the term `3+4`). When I change that line to use `=` (assignment, more precisely unification) instead of `is` (arithmetic evaluation) like so

```
source_removal([], []). % Second parameter is empty list due to risk of a cycle
source_removal(G,Toposort):-member([D,_], G), 
                            doesnt_depend_on(G,D), 
                            remove_graph_node(G,D,SubG),
                            source_removal(SubG, SubTopoSort),
                            append([D], SubTopoSort, AppendResult),
                            Toposort = AppendResult.
```

I get the following result:

```
?- source_removal([ [a,[b,e,f]], [b,[f,g]], [c,[g,d]], [d,[h]], [e,[f]], [f,[]], [g,[h]], [h,[]] ], Result).
Result = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h] ;
Result = [a, b, c, d, e, g, f, h] ;
Result = [a, b, c, d, e, g, h, f] ;
Result = [a, b, c, d, g, e, f, h] ;
Result = [a, b, c, d, g, e, h, f] ;
Result = [a, b, c, d, g, h, e, f] ;
Result = [a, b, c, e, d, f, g, h] ;
Result = [a, b, c, e, d, g, f, h] ;
Result = [a, b, c, e, d, g, h, f] ;
Result = [a, b, c, e, f, d, g, h] ;
Result = [a, b, c, e, f, g, d, h] ;
...
Result = [c, d, a, e, b, g, h, f] ;
false.
```

(Shortened, it shows 140 solutions in total.)

**Edit**: I didn't check all the solutions, but among the ones it finds is the one you gave in your example (`[a,e,b,f,c,g,d,h]`), and they look plausible in the sense that each either starts with `a` or with `c`.